# Add the Show Package Contents in a folder

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to add extensions in my Cocoa application. I don't like the .bundle extension so I want to make my own. When I make my own, it will just be a folder of the files. I want to implement something like this:

[image]

But I do not know how to.

Here is what I want to do:
`mybundle.myextensionname.bundle` => `mybundle.myextensionname`

Answer (score 1):

After a few minutes of trying I found the answer

you need this

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
                        <string>LSTypeIsPackage</string>
                        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
                        <string>Default</string>
                    </dict>
                </array>
```

**Full Code**

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
                    <string>LSTypeIsPackage</string>
                    <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
                    <string>Default</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>unextension</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Unique Extension</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Default</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.buddhiman.Unique-Extension</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).Document</string>
        </dict>
        <dict/>
    </array>
    <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.apple.package</string>
                <string>public.composite-content</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>Unique Extension</string>
            <key>UTTypeIcons</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.buddhiman.Unique-Extension</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>unextension</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```